# Hide and seek game and raycasting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on multiplayer collaboration in *Unity3d* using *Smartfox Server2x.*

But I wish to change it in to a hide and seek game.

When the hider  (third person controller)  presses the button "seek me" the seeker tries to find the hider. But I don't know  How can I identify when a seeker sees the hider. Is it possible using *Raycasting*. If yes how? Please help me.

```
 void Update () {

    RaycastHit hit;
    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position,transform.forward,out hit,50))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.name=="Deccan Peninsula1")
        {
            Debug.Log("detect.................");
        }
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag =="Tree")
        {
            Debug.Log("detect.........cube........");
            //Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Unity Answers by duck](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/8003/how-can-i-know-if-a-gameobject-is-seen-by-a-partic.html):

> There's a whole slew of ways to achieve this, depending on the precise
>   functionality you need.
>
> You can get events when an object is visible within a certain camera,
>   and when it enters or leaves, using these functions:
>
> [OnWillRenderObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.OnWillRenderObject.html), [Renderer.isVisible](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html),
>   [Renderer.OnBecameVisible](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameVisible.html), and [OnBecameInvisible](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.OnBecameInvisible.html)
>
> Or you can calculate whether an object's bounding box falls within the
>   camera's view frustum, using these two functions:
>
> [GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html)
>   [GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html)
>
> If you've already determined that the object is within the camera's
>   view frustum, you could cast a ray from the camera to the object in
>   question, to see whether there are any objects blocking its view.
>   [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could do many things to find out if a seeker has found the hider. I am going to suggest how I would do it and I will try to make the idea/code as efficient as possible.

Each [GameObject](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html) knows its position via the transform component. You can check how close one object is from the other by creating a ratio and comparing how close they are from each other. The moment both objects are close to each other then you enter a new state. In this state you will fire a [RayCast](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) only when the direction/angle of view of the seeker changes. So think of it this way, your seeker is looking around and as he is spinning he is firing the RayCast. The main idea is not to fire way too many RayCasts all the time which will hinder performance. Make sure your RayCast ignores everything except who you are looking for.

*If you get stuck you can ask a more specific question, probably regarding RayCast and how to make them ignore walls or not shoot through walls, or maybe you discover that solution on your own.*

Good luck!

Comment: @DEEPS how about taking the information given to you and reading up on the documentation? Then try and see how that all works. If you get stuck, or something is unclear, then you can ask a targeted question again.

Comment: As instructions from FunctionR i tried a sample raycast programfor a basic knowldge but i didn't get any result... why? this is the code for instantiate a player .                                            var brick : Transform;
     function Start () {
   
      Instantiate(brick, Vector3 (1, 1, 0), Quaternion.identity);
            
        }                                                                Drag raycast physics script code on the player  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html

Comment: Because there's nothing in front of the object? (Keep in mind that forward is defined as Vector3(0,0,1))